# Can't build my xamarin ios project due to of provisioning profile error

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

We develope multiple Xamarin apps. On Android devices works everything fine. The problem comes with iOS. Testing the app on the simulator works totally fine, but deploying my app for testing purposes does not work. IMO Visual Studio for Mac is pretty useless for getting information what went wrong.. So i try it here

When deploying to my iPhone i get following error in my "Deploying to Device" tab
[Deploying to Device Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNAZk.png)

In the Application Output i this error
[Application Output Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgwXC.png)

These things I already tried:

- delete all provisioning profiles from my macbook
- create an app in xcode with the same identifier and run this app (works fine)
- checked if every certificate is valid (yeah, they are)
- probably every answer of questions regarding this topic

Maybe anyone of you has faced this issue and knows something i did not think about..

Comment: 1. The first error could be caused by an invalid provisioning profile, please try to create an empty project and in Bundle Signing -> Choose Automatic Provisioning and then rebuild it to see it it works,if failed, you may need to create a [new one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=macos). 2. The second error could be caused by [instruments service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/using-instruments-to-detect-native-leaks-using-markheap) running in back-end, you may need to end it.